# how to format a SQL Server date according to a specific pattern?

Tags: sql-server-2008, date, format

In MySQL there's the DATE_FORMAT() function that allows to represent a given date value according to the specified pattern.

Is there something like it in MS SQL Server?

The statement I'm trying to format is:

`SELECT TOP 1 CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), ot.Timestamp,110) AS 'TS' FROM ot, cl WHERE ot.CompID = cl.CompID;`

Which outputs as MM-DD-YYYY. There are other styles, but I haven't found one that suits me.

I need something that outputs as DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM. Where HH is 24 hour format.

How can I best do this?

Comment: Why can't you just return the date and leave the formatting to the application around it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx). Looks like you can use the following:

```
select convert(varchar(10), getdate(), 103) + ' ' + convert(varchar(8), getdate(), 108)
```

Answer (score 3):

From SQL Server 2012 you can use the [FORMAT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213505.aspx?ppud=4) function.

```
 SELECT getdate(), FORMAT (getdate(), ' dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm').
```

http://www.sql-server-helper.com/sql-server-2012/format-function-vs-convert-function.aspx

Comment: They are trying to do this in MS SQL Server.